# Why does my iterator.next result in a ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, iterator

I am making a game where you as a player eat dots... These dots spawn randomly and when the player covers the dots they should be removed. To do this I am using an Iterator.

```
ArrayList<Dot> dots = new ArrayList<Dot>();
Iterator<Dot> i = dots.iterator();

public Game(){
    MouseHandler.mouse = new MouseHandler();
    Player.player = new Player(40, 40);

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        dots.add(new Dot());
    }
}

public void update(){
    Player.player.update();

    while(i.hasNext()){
        Dot current = i.next();
        if(Player.player.getCircle().intersects(current.getCircle())){
            i.remove();
        }
    }

}
```

When doing this i get a `ConcurretModificationException` at the `Dot current = i.next();`

What is the cause of this problem, why is it happening?

-Sincerely Henrik

**EDIT:** Sorry for being so troublesome I was just trying to make the code shorter and more readable.

**EDIT2:** Thanks everyone... The problem was that I had not added anything to the collection before creating an Iterator. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Use I.remove() instead.

Comment: Because you're modifying the list you're iterating over through the list and not the iterator.

Comment: No that is not the problem... Using i.remove didn't work

Comment: @Devtons Then you'll need to provide more information, because what you're doing will cause that error, and removing it through the iterator won't.

Comment: Nothing should be removed because there is nothing in dots to remove, at least in the code as written. Please provide code which replicates the problem.

Comment: Sorry I have now edited the code so you will see when i add dots to the dots arraylist

Comment: Still not enough information; the issue isn't with the adding of dots.

Comment: Please write code that will compile. Your code is not syntactically valid (there is a ctor in the middle of some other method, or missing a method around the code doing the removal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the iterator in the initial field assignment, which is presumably happening before you add anything to the collection in the constructor.

Remove the iterator field and just call `dots.iterator()`, assigning to a local variable, immediately before the while loop.

Comment: Incidentally, even if you hadn't been removing items, you would have found a problem in the iterator-as-a-member-variable approach: on the second (and subsequent) times you called update, the iterator would be exhausted, so the call would be a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the exception because you are modifying the collection directly and not via the iterator.

You can remove from the iterator using `i.remove()` instead.

Comment: I get the same ConcurrentModificationException